# How to submit AJAX form in grails w/out using a submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, grails

I have this `g:formRemote` which submits a form using ajax.

```
<g:formRemote name="listAll" update="menuItemAJAX" url="[controller: 'superWaiter',  action:'menuItem']" onSuccess="additionalContent()">                   
    <a href="#" id="all" class="list-group-item" onclick="myFunction()">All</a>
</g:formRemote>
```

I dont want to use a button since it is easier to style links. It does not work with

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction(){
        $('#listAll').submit();
    };
</script>
```

Btw, the id of the form is `listAll` since it gets it from the `name` attr

Comment: The code used to submit a remote form isn't as simple as calling submit on the form. use a button, then view the source of the rendered page in your browser. Pay attention to what code is generated by Grails and then replicate that code for your link and get rid of the button.

Comment: Use remoteLink: <g:remoteLink action="show" id="1" update="success" before="if(!confirm('Are you sure?')) return false">Test 5</g:remoteLink> Anyway, the design part should be defined in your css, no matter a button or a link.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [link to a blog post](http://programmingitch.blogspot.com/2011/01/grails-ajax-examples.html) I wrote a couple years ago that contains a sample of each of the Grails Ajax invocations you can make and here's the [link to the code on GitHub](https://github.com/mikemil/AjaxExamples).  There is also an updated version written for Grails 2.x.